# Why are my eigenvectors very correlated after PCA

Tags: correlation, pca, orange

I have a set of a few thousands records with 6000 variables. I am performing a PCA in orange, keeping only the 10 firsts components.

When plotting the resulting Eigenvectors, I found that they seemed quite very correlated. I thus put the correlation widget to compute the pairwise correlations. And it gave me very high absolute values of correlations `(more than 0.2 and up to 0.7)`

Below is the flow made in orange :

```
(CSV) -data-> (PCA) -EigenVectors-> (Transpose) -Data-> (Correlations)
```

The question is then why are my eigenvectors correlated?

If anyone has any idea of where does this comes, it would ease my mind.

Thanks alot,

Answer (score 0):

The PCA eigenvectors form an orthonormal basis. However that does not imply that they are uncorrelated.

For instance the standard unit vectors in 3D ([1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]) are all correlated with a coefficient of -0.5.

Comment: Well, since correlation is a scalar product, it seems that PCA should return an orthonormal basis with respect to that scalar product...